# What is the fastest way to get data into Cassandra 2 from a Java application?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql3

I have tried the DataStax Java driver and it seems the fastest way to insert data is to compose a CQL string with all parameters inline.

This loop takes 2500ms or so on my test cluster:

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO perf_test.wibble (id, info) VALUES (?, ?)")
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) session.execute(ps.bind("" + i, "aa" + i));
```

The same loop with the parameters inline is about 1300ms. It gets worse if there are many parameters. I know I can use batching to insert all the rows at once but thats not the purpose of this test. I also tried using `session.execute(cql, params)` and it is faster but still doesn't match inline values.

Composing CQL strings is certainly convenient and simple but is there a much faster way?

Comment: IIRC, some performance measurements I've seen gave about 4000 queries per second per node, so 6× performance might be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do two things to improve performance. First is to use the [executeAsynch](http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/developer/java-driver/asynchronous_t.html) function in the driver instead of `execute`.

Second thing is to use a [batch statement](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0) instead of a loop (I know you mentioned it's not the purpose of the test, but when it comes to inserts with a loop, batching is what you want).

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO messages (user_id, msg_id, title, body) " +
                                       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid1, title1, body1));
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid2, title2, body2));
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid3, title3, body3));
session.execute(batch);
```

Comment: The work will already be done by a thread pool loading data from elsewhere so using exec async doesn't help me all that much. I have tested a BatchStatement as you suggest but I got better performance by creating my own BATCH in CQL and inlining the parameters.

Comment: @DavidTinker If you are multi threading the load, does the time per thread (the latency) really matter? That seems to be the figure you are reporting.

Comment: @Raedwald Thats true. I did notice that it always seems to be faster to just inline parameter values and not use PreparedStatements. I was wondering how many other performance surprises were lurking around. Rather ask here that have to figure them all out the hard way!

Comment: I have done some more testing and this is definitely the fastest way to go. My scripts are on Github https://github.com/davidtinker/cassandra-perf

Comment: What is the preferred batch size to optimize performance? or does performance get better when increasing batch size?

Comment: I get an error when the batch size is over 4000 or so... It says expected 0 or 1 but got 13. But, this is super fast otherwise. Maybe it is running out of memory.